# Assistance with a BM exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

A friend and I are attempting to answer part 3) of the exercise quoted below (from [*Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540643257)) regarding Brownian Motion (BM). We have some questions apropos thereof.

To show that $(X^{\mu}, X^{\nu})$ is Gaussian, we argued that $X^{\mu}$ and $X^{\nu}$ are individually Gaussian because their defining integrals are limits of convex combinations of simple functions, each of which is Gaussian, and since the Gaussian subspace is closed, the result is Gaussian. **Is that reasoning correct? Is there another (better) way to conclude that the pair is Gaussian?**

**May I please have a hint for showing that $E[X^{\mu}X^{\nu}] = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\inf(s,t) \, d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) = (h,g)$?** Here's what we tried in attempt to show the 2nd equality, that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\inf(s,t) \, d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) = (h,g)$ (we didn't have a clue for the first equality): Split the integral up according to whether $s<t$ or $s>t$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\inf(s,t) \, d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) &= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}s \, d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) + \int_{0}^{1}\int_{t}^{1}t \, d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} 1\cdot h'(s) \, ds \, d\nu(t) + \int_{0}^{1} t \mu(]t,1])\,d\nu(t) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} h(t) \, d\mu(t) + \int_{0}^{1} t \mu(]t,1])\,d\nu(t)\\
&= (h,g) + \int_{0}^{1} t \mu(]t,1])\,d\nu(t),
\end{align*}
$$
but we can't show that the second term is zero (and I don't think it is). **Is what we've done here correct?**

> **(1.12) Exercise.** We denote by $H$ the subspace of $C[0,1]$ of functions $h$ such that
>   $h(0)=0$, $h$ is absolutely continuous and its derivative $h'$ (which
>   exists a.e.) satisfies  $$\int_{0}^{1} h'(s)^{2}\, ds < +\infty. $$ 1)
>   Prove that $H$ is a Hilbert space for the scalar product $$ (g,h) = \int_{0}^{1} g'(s)h'(s)\, ds. $$
>
> 2) For any bounded measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, show that there exists an
>   element $h$ in $H$ such that for every $f \in H$ $$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\, d\mu(x) = (f,h) $$ and $h'(s) = \mu(]s,1])$.
>
> 3) Let $B$ be a standard linear BM, $\mu$ and $\nu$ two
>   bounded measures associated as in 2) with $h$ and $g$. Prove that $$X^{\mu}(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1} B_{s}(\omega)\,d\mu(s) \quad \text{and} \quad X^{\nu}(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1} B_{s}(\omega)\,d\nu(s) $$ are
>   random variables, that the pair $(X^{\mu}, X^{\nu})$ is Gaussian and
>   that  $$ E[X^{\mu}X^{\nu}] = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\inf(s,t) \,
> > d\mu(s) \, d\nu(t) = (h,g). $$

Comment: This is not homework.

Comment: @RonGordon The title is already for the benefit of English speakers.

Comment: Quinn: I apologize - I was being a little cheeky.

Comment: One thing to say: it appears you are applying the inner product $(s,h)$  to the second line, but really you must be using $s \chi_{s < t}$, which is not in $C[0,1]$, so you should be careful. Perhaps you should throw in the rest of the interval and subtract it back out and put it to the other side?

Comment: @Evan I think it's okay because C[0,1] embeds densely in $L^{1}$. Do you agree?

Comment: @QuinnCulver I don't agree about the embedding. At the very least you would have to use $s \chi_{s < t} + t \chi_{s>t}$. Maybe that's what's missing? PS. The dense embedding doesn't mean the Hilbert space structure can be carried there, too.

Comment: I do not understand the "proof" that $(X^\mu,X^\nu)$ is gaussian. You prove that $X^\mu$ and $X^\nu$ are gaussian, then what exactly? You might want to explain "since the Gaussian subspace is closed, the result is Gaussian".

Comment: @Did What else is needed to show that the pair is Gaussian beyond knowing that each is Gaussian?

Comment: By definition, a vector is gaussian if and only if every linear combination of its entries is (real) gaussian.

Comment: I feel I must be missing something: since the Gaussians form a subspace, mustn't a linear combination of $X^\mu$ and $X^\nu$ be Gaussian? Is that all there is to it?

Comment: @Did First: I forgot to @ you above. Second: my point above is that I'm assuming the chapter 0 material of this book where it's stated that the Gaussians form a closed subspace. Whether I could prove that is another matter...

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to address other questions.

The reasoning for Gaussians seems right, would do the same.

The first equality you  can use linearity of expectation and the fact that for $s<t$, $B_t = (B_t - B_s)  +  B_s$ where this decomposition is a sum of independent mean 0 Gaussians. Putting the expectation inside the integral , only $E(B_s^2) = s$ survives.

Your solution is almost correct for the second equality:
It appears you are applying the inner product $(s,h)$  to the second line, but really you are using $s \chi_{s < t}$, which is not in $C[0,1]$, so you should be careful. If  you replace with $f(s) = s \chi_{s < t} + t \chi_{s > t}$, which doesn't change your integral when you convert to the inner product, then you would subtract the integral of $\int_{t}^1 t d\mu(s)$ which cancels the term on the other side.